# how to access one cordova plugin inside another cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to access the Cordova BarcodeScanner plugin inside the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin. How can I access that plugin?

I am using InAppBrowser in my Cordova project but my BarcodeScanner plugin is not accessible inside the Cordova InAppBrowser. I have tried many things but it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it within inappbrowser. The whole point of inappbrowser is to provide a safe way to browse untrusted third party websites that prevents them having access to native functionality through cordova. You'd need to open the website in the main webview - but this would have a whole host of security implications.

Comment: How can we open the website in the main webview. Cordova itself is a webview and to open any url in cordova we need inappbrowser. I m not understanding your point of opening website in main webview. Can you please elaborate.
Thank you

Comment: In your config.xml, just put ```<content src="www.mywebsite/index.html" />```

Comment: I have native storage plugin, i want to add encryption of stored data, i want to use aes encrytion plugin in native storage plugin any solution for that ?